# How can OpenSSL Secret Keys be imported into GnuPG?

Tags: conversion, gnupg, import, openssl

I want to `import` the `secret key` from a OpenSSL x509 (Client) Certificate into `GnuPG` (NOT gpgsm for S/MIME!)

I have seen there are utilities to convert GPG Keys into SSH Format [1] and even create x509 Certificates [2] from your GPG Key. But no tools to convert *to* GnuPG Format.

Importing into gpgsm worked perfectly using:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in gpg-certs.pem -inkey gpg-key.pem -out gpg-key.p12
gpgsm --import gpg-key.p12
```

It then shows up with a `key type: 4096 bit RSA` when issuing `gpgsm --list-secret-keys`

Trying something similar with `GnuPG` however does **not** work, since the format is not GPG:

```
gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import gpg-key.pem
```

**Is there any Tool or Method which I have not found to convert from OpenSSL to GPG?**

[1] gpgkey2ssh tool

[2] http://wiki.cacert.org/ConvertingPgpKeyToCertificate

Comment: For those wondering WHY I want to do this, the goal is to after write the key to a GnuPG Smartcard using the `keytocard` command. For this it **must** to be in the GnuPG database.

Comment: You could read the OpenPGP specs (it's not "GnuPG" format), and hand-craft such a key. Though, doesn't `gpgsm` also support smartcards?